# Why do we need connections, if we have the Lie derivative?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

When I learned about the covariant derivative, it was motivated as a way of defining a good differentiation operation on tensors. To do this, we had to define a connection on the manifold, which was a substantial extra piece of structure.

However, the Lie derivative requires no connection at all; it just requires a vector field $V^\mu$ defined on the manifold. In particular, since we've already chosen coordinates, we can define the Lie derivative in any direction $n^\mu$ by using the vector field $V = n^\mu \partial_\mu$, which requires zero extra structure. Then $\mathcal{L}_V$ seems to be a perfectly good replacement for $n^\mu \nabla_\mu$.  At the very least, it does everything that books say the covariant derivative was meant to do. Ignoring all the stuff the covariant derivative ends up getting used for, I don't know why we would have introduced it in the first place.

What good properties does $n^\mu \nabla_\mu$ have that $\mathcal{L}_{n^\mu \partial_\mu}$ does not?

Comment: (+1) related: [Exterior Derivative vs. Covariant Derivative vs. Lie Derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/209241/), [Physicist's request for intuition on covariant derivatives and Lie derivatives](http://mathoverflow.net/q/75220/).

Comment: Covariant derivative is scalar-field linear in one entry Lie derivative is not in both entries  This feature strongly distinguishes between the two operators. The choice depends on which feature you need.

Comment: The Lie derivative does not give rise to a notion of parallel transport. It is how one vector field changes along another, it doesn't *connect* the tangent spaces at different points. Also, this is a pure differential geometry, not a physics question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sure, but it gives some notion of transport, by pullback/push forward. Why is that not good enough?

Comment: @knzhou But that transport is highly nonunique: it depends on the choice of $V$. The choice of a connection $\nabla$ does not depend on some arbitrary vector field, and in the Riemannian case, one can select a unique $\nabla$ with desirable properties.

Comment: Loosely speaking(about the need/use), the lie derivative has its significance when dealing with invariant quantities, while the connection is a pretty general tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One distinctive feature is that the [connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_%28mathematics%29) $\nabla$ has the [tensor field property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field) in its first entry $\nabla_{fX}=f\nabla_{X}$, while the [Lie derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) doesn't. We have ${\cal L}_{fX}\neq f{\cal L}_{X}$ generically.

There are already manifestly covariant explanations on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209241/11127) and [Mathoverflow.SE](https://mathoverflow.net/q/75220/13917). Let's for simplicity consider a local coordinate patch $U$ with coordinates $x^{\mu}$. The tensor field property implies that the covariant derivative $\nabla_{X}=X^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}$ is completely determine by some directional derivatives $\nabla_{\mu}$. Not so for the Lie derivative.

Say that we are given a metric tensor field $g$ and some tensor field $T$. Assume for simplicity that the tensor field components $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $T^{\mu_1 \ldots \mu_r}{}_{\nu_1 \ldots \nu_s}$ in the given local coordinate system are constant, i.e. $x$-independent. Let $\nabla$ be the [Levi-Civita connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection). Then $\nabla_Xg=0$ and $\nabla_XT=0$ as we would expect from a directional derivative (since after all, the tensor field components are constant in one coordinate system). But ${\cal L}_{X}g\neq 0$ and ${\cal L}_{X}T\neq 0$ generically.